# Trying to make the entire TR clickable in rails without _path

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a TR clickable. I have it clicking, but the code below is throwing weird db data above my table and the URL is wrong.

```
<tr data-link="<%= link_to x.status, :controller => :requester, :action => :call, :am_request_id => x.id.to_s %>"  class="<%= class_for_status(x.status) %>">
```

Here is the URL result when clicked --> (herokuapp.com/requester/a%20href=)

If I use this code below the TR link is working, but the URL is wrong?

```
<tr data-link="<%= requester_call_path(x.id.to_s) %>" class="<%= class_for_status(x.status) %>">
```

Here is the URL result when clicked --> (herokuapp.com/requester/call.56440300)

The 56440300 above is the ID

============

This below is of course what should happen when clicking the URL

herokuapp.com/requester/call?am_id=56440300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a path method, you can specify param's name like following :

```
<%= requester_call_path(am_id: x.id.to_s) %>
```

Hope this helps